# constructor with strings and calendar for birthdate

Tags: java, string, constructor, calendar, gregorian-calendar

So we had to make a Adressbook with Contacts and they all have name, surname, adress, email, phonenumber and birthdate.
While everything else is saved as a String, the birthdate has to be "Calendar". This is what I got so far:

```
public class PrivateContact extends Contact {

private Calendar Geburtsdatum = (GregorianCalendar) Calendar.getInstance();

public PrivateContact(String Vorname, String Nachname, String Adresse,
        String Email, String Telnum, Calendar Geburtsdatum) {
    super(Vorname, Nachname, Adresse, Email, Telnum);
    this.Geburtsdatum = Geburtsdatum;       
}
```

But my problem is, that in the testing class, the format of the constructor with string,String,....,Calendar isn't working. Eclipse always gives the "help" that I have to change the type of the constructor from string,...,calendar to string,...,string , but I that's exactly what I don't want to do.
I know that the "01.01.1900" is a String, but I need a Calendar type of it, so how do I change it? How do I tell it that it has to be a calendar type?
Here's how the constructor in the testing class is used:

```
Contact person1 = new PrivateContact("Max", "Muster", "Fooville", "maxi@student.at", "0123456789", "01.01.1900");
```

I really hope someone can help me!!!

Comment: why don't you use `Date` for `birthdate` instead of `Calendar`???

Comment: yeah I would, but for this work it is required that it has o be Calendar type..

Answer (score 2):

Use the following to instantiate a calendar and then pass on to your test.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DATE,1);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,1);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,1900);
```

Other option is to change your constructor to accept String and then convert to Calendar within the constructor or some other utility.

```
public PrivateContact(String Vorname, String Nachname, String Adresse,
    String Email, String Telnum, String sGeburtsdatum) {
    super(Vorname, Nachname, Adresse, Email, Telnum);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
Date date = df.parse(sGeburtsdatum);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
this.Geburtsdatum = cal;       
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but as this is used as a Adressbook, the one using is has to be able  to create a new contact with the constructor. And I just can't do this form for every contact which is stored there.

Comment: How about implementing this conversion inside your constructor. Change the PrivateContact constructor to accept a String instead of Calndar and convert to Calendar using the following code.    String sDate = "01.01.1900";
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
  Date date = df.parse(sDate);
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(date);

Answer (score 0):

It is working, but "01.01.1900" is a String, not an instance of Calendar.

check this part of the official tutorials for Calendar related material:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/index.html

Comment: I know but how can I change that?? How do I tell that the date has to be used as a Calendar type?

Comment: instantiate a Calendar, or a Date, as Ankit Lamba suggests.